# Unwind segue "Property of 'BusStopItem' not found on type 'AddBusStopViewController'"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, segue

this question is based on the apple x-code tutorial [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/ThirdTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH10-SW1).

I am having an error when I call my `unwindBusList` function which looks at the source of the segue. I have tested it with these lines commented out and everything else seems to run fine other than the `BusStopItem` not being added.

> Property of BusStopItem' not found on type
>   'AddBusStopViewController'

on this line:

```
BusStopItem *item = source.busStopItem;
```

YourBusStopsTableViewController.m

```
#import "YourBusStopsTableViewController.h"
#import "BusStopItem.h"
#import "AddBusStopViewController.h"


@interface YourBusStopsTableViewController ()

@property NSMutableArray *busStopItems;

- (IBAction)unwindBusList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;
@end

@implementation YourBusStopsTableViewController

- (IBAction)unwindBusList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    AddBusStopViewController *source = segue.sourceViewController;
    BusStopItem *item = source.busStopItem;
    if (item != nil) {
        [self.busStopItems addObject:item];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

AddBusStopViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "BusStopItem.h"

@interface AddBusStopViewController : UIViewController

@property BusStopItem *busStopItem;

@end
```

AddBusStopViewController.m

```
#import "AddBusStopViewController.h"

@interface AddBusStopViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *saveButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *stopNumField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;

@end

@implementation AddBusStopViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if (sender != self.saveButton) return;

    if (self.nameField.text.length > 0 && self.stopNumField.text.length > 0) {
        self.busStopItem = [[BusStopItem alloc] init];
        self.busStopItem.itemName = self.nameField.text;
        self.busStopItem.stopNum = [self.stopNumField.text intValue];
        self.busStopItem.fetching = NO;
    }

}


@end
```

BusStopItem.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface BusStopItem : NSObject

@property NSString *itemName;
@property NSInteger stopNum;
@property BOOL fetching;

@end
```

Any and all feedback is appreciated, this has been bugging me for hours, and nothing has solved my problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you using the exact same code pasted here ? Because the error description not matching with your code.

Comment: Yes, I just checked, I can link a repo.https://github.com/Dutchgoose/BusApp

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the objective-c files I created for the views were not in the appropriate directory. Although they appeared in xcode to be in the correct location (and actually were), these versions weren't being updated as I was saving. I replaced the files that were not being written to with the appropriate ones and everything works.